# Cannot pass .env variables into .aab file in React Native

Tags: android, react-native, mobile, environment-variables

I have a React Native project and in emulator, it works fine. I get .aab file and upload it to Play Store, but after releasing it there, the app does not read the .env variables, so the app crashes. I searched a lot but solutions are completely different and i am confused as hell. How can i pass .env variables into .aab file so, the app can work in Play Store?

Thanks in advance!!!